# Find all possible values $m$ such that $f(x)=x^2-5mx+10m-4$ has 2 roots and one of them is twice as the other

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-5mx+10m-4$, find $m$ such that there exist a number $a$ that satisfies $f(a)=f(2a)=0$. This was my attempt:

$f(a)=f(2a)$ 
$a^2-5ma+10m-4=4a^2-10ma+10m-4$ 
$a^2-5ma=4a^2-10ma$ 
$-3a^2+5ma=0$ 
$a*(-3a+5m)=0$

If $a=0$ then $f(a)=10m-4=0$ and $m=\frac{2}{5}$, else if $-3+5m=0$ then I can't solve.

Is my first answer correct? And if yes, how do I solve for the second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation *always* has two roots: $2$ and $5m-2$. So, one of them is twice the other if and only if $m=\frac65$ or if $m=\frac35$.

In your approach, it seems that you forgot that you should also have $f(a)=0$.

Comment: How do I prove that it has those 2 roots?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: I'm sorry but are there any other approaches since I'm not allowed to use the quadratic formula yet?

Comment: Since\begin{align}f(x)&=x^2-4-5mx+10m\\&=(x-2)(x+2)-5m(x-2)\\&=(x-2)(x+2-5m),\end{align}the roots of $f(x)$ are $2$ amd $5m-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the roots be $\alpha, 2\alpha$.

By Vieta's formulas,

Sum of roots $=3\alpha = 5m$, product of roots $=2\alpha^2 = 10m-4$.

Hence, $2(\frac{5m}3)^2 = 10m-4 \\ \implies 25m^2 - 45m +18 = 0$, we get (by simple factorisation) $m=0.6$ or $1.2$.

Test by plugging these back into the original expression and getting $f(x) = x^2-3x+2$ and $f(x) = x^2 - 6x+8$ respectively, which each have two distinct roots with one twice the other.

Answer (score 1):

The given equation can be written as

$\begin{align}
f(x)& =x^2-4-5mx+10m\\
&=(x-2) (x+2) -5m(x-2) \\
&=(x-2) (x+2-5m) 
\end{align}$

Now, we have two possibilities: $\alpha=2\beta$ or $\beta=2\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without making use of the quadratic formula is to apply the Factor Theorem.  If the zeroes of $ \ x^2 - 5mx + (10m-4) \ $ are $ \ x = a \ $ and $ \ x = 2a \ \ , $ then we can write the polynomial as
$$ x^2  \ - \  5mx \ + \ (10m - 4) \ \ = \ \ ( x - a ) · (x - 2a) \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ - \ 3ax \ + \ 2a^2 \ \ . $$

Making the correspondences between the linear and constant terms of the two expressions gives us  $ \ -3a \ = \ -5m \ $ and $ \ 2a^2 \ = \ 10m - 4 \ \ . $  (This avoids the problem of needing to "see" how to factor the given polynomial.  This also makes it evident how the Viete relations in **Deepak**'s answer arise.)  The first of these equations tells us that $ \ m \ = \ \frac35·a \ \ , $ which we can then insert into the second equation to obtain
$$ 2a^2 \ - \ 10m \ + \ 4 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ - \ 5·\left(\frac35·a \right) \ + \ 2 \ \ = \ \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ - \ 3a   \ + \ 2 \ \ = \ \ (a \ - \ 1) · (a \ - \ 2) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

We find that either $ \ a = 1 \ $ or $ \ a = 2 \ \ , $ which makes $ \ 2a \ $ equal to either $ \ 2 \ $ or $ \ 4 \ \ . $  (This agrees with conclusions in other posted answers that one of the zeroes of the polynomial *must* be $ \ 2 \ \ . ) $  Returning to the relation $ \ m \ = \ \frac35·a \ \ , $ the only possible values for $ \ m \ $ are thus $ \ \frac35 \ $ or  $ \ \frac65 \ \ . $